# How to reuse containers using TestContainers in scala?

Tags: scala, testcontainers

I have a few containers that running using TestConatiners and I have a few services that I want to test. for each service, I have a separate file (test suite) and inside I have tests.
I have a class that I defined the logic of containers - beforeAll I start the containers, and afterAll I stop the all containers, and all test suits files extend this class.
The problem starts during switching test suits, I want to keep the containers running, instead of stopping and rerunning for each test suite which causes to slow extremely the testing pipeline.

this is a good example of what I mean - https://callistaenterprise.se/blogg/teknik/2020/10/09/speed-up-your-testcontainers-tests/

but the issue is that we don't have static in Scala

Any suggestion on how can I do that using testconatiners-scala ?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same behavior in Scala using a companion object
https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/singleton-objects.html

```scala
object AbstractContainerBaseSpec {
  private val containerDef =
    GenericContainer.Def(
      "redis:5.0.3-alpine", // whatever image you need
      exposedPorts = Seq(6379),
    ).start()
}

// extend this abstract class with your test class
abstract class AbstractContainerBaseSpec {}
```

This should be the same as the Singleton container pattern mentioned in your example and as described in the official docs
https://www.testcontainers.org/test_framework_integration/manual_lifecycle_control/#singleton-containers

```java
abstract class AbstractContainerBaseTest {

    static final MySQLContainer MY_SQL_CONTAINER;

    static {
        MY_SQL_CONTAINER = new MySQLContainer();
        MY_SQL_CONTAINER.start();
    }
}
```

I created a minimal demo to show this behavior here: https://github.com/bauerei/testcontainers-scala-singleton-demo